# htaccess rewrite uri if starts with uploads or does not have extension

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'am trying to create a htaccess-file with the following rewriterule: The uri doesn't end with jpeg, jpg, png,... Except when the uri starts with '/uploads/'.

So rewrite to index.php:
HOST /uploads/file1.jpg
HOST /home/dashboard

But do not rewrite:
HOST /images/banner.jpg

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ((\/uploads\/)([-a-z0-9_/\.]+))|(([-a-z0-9_/\.]+)!\.(jpeg|jpg|png))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}ci.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTP_HOST` doesn't match request URI. It just matches domain name in a HTTP request.

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|ico|tiff|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ ci.php [L]
```